# Linear gradient on background image hover

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to add a linear gradient background to my background image as if it were an overlay effect but without success

code:

```
const Test = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://ak5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/16730485/thumb/1.jpg");
  cursor: pointer;
  :hover{

  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return <Test />;
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bardeen-zl72m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-curie-2p32m

```
const bgImage = `url("https://ak5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/16730485/thumb/1.jpg")`
const bgGradient = `linear-gradient(to right, #f003, #0f03)`

const Test = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: ${bgImage};
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-image: ${bgGradient}, ${bgImage};
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return <Test />;
}
```

Comment: i try use this but dont work:     background-image: url(${({ bgOne }) => bgOne}) , ${linearGradient};

Comment: const linearGradient = `linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)
)`;

Comment: What is `bgOne` ?

Comment: is one img object import TestBG from 'assets/images/xd.png'; i pass with styled comp props

Comment: Try assigning the string `'assets/images/xd.png';` directly to `bgOne`, instead of using import